# How can I decouple objects from a SQLAlchemy session such that I can insert them into a different database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two databases (`src` and `dst`) and each database uses the same SQLAlchemy model. I would like to query `src` and insert the results of that query into `dst`.

When I attempt to insert the values from `src` into `dst`, my code throws a `InvalidRequestError` exception because the queried objects are attached to the `src` session.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.exc import InvalidRequestError
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    gid = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    password = Column(String)
    gecos = Column(String)
    home_directory = Column(String)
    shell = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, passwd_string):
        passwd_fields = passwd_string.split(':')
        self.username = passwd_fields[0]
        self.password = passwd_fields[1]
        self.uid = passwd_fields[2]
        self.gid = passwd_fields[3]
        self.gecos = passwd_fields[4]
        self.home_directory = passwd_fields[5]
        self.shell = passwd_fields[6]


def get_session(db_uri):
    engine = create_engine(db_uri)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    return sessionmaker(bind=engine)()


def add_users(session, user_list):
    session.add_all(user_list)
    session.commit()


def main():
    users = [
        User('root:x:0:0:Root User:/:/bin/bash'),
        User('genuser:x:100:100:Generic User:/home/user:/bin/bash')
    ]

    # insert users to src database
    src = get_session('sqlite:///src.sqlite')
    add_users(src, users)

    # query src database for users
    src_users = src.query(User).all()

    # insert users found in src database into dst database
    try:
        dst = get_session('sqlite:///dst.sqlite')
        add_users(dst, src_users)
    except InvalidRequestError as error:
        print "InvalidRequestError: {}".format(error)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running above code generates the following exception/error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Object '<User at 0x10bc10250>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')
```

In response to @Deepak's answer, I implemented a `copy()` method in User:

```
def copy(self):
    return User(
        '{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(
            self.username,
            self.password,
            self.uid,
            self.gid,
            self.gecos,
            self.home_directory,
            self.shell
        )
    )
```

Which means I can now do:

```
try:
    dst = get_session('sqlite:///dst.sqlite')
    dst.add(user.copy()) for user in src_users
except InvalidRequestError as error:
    print "InvalidRequestError: {}".format(error)
```

Comment: In case it helps: here's a script to copy entire databases using sqlalchemy http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/apr/27/copying-databases-across-platforms-sqlalchemy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to query via Session of Database 1 and inserting the attached user object of this session to another session.
A better way would be inserting the values in 2nd table in the same way you are inserting in 1st table. 
So get the values from table 1:

```
src_users = src.query(User).all()
duplicate_records = []
for row in src.query(User).all(): 
    duplicate_user.append(User(row.username +":"+ row.password +":"+str(row.uid)+":"+str(row.gid)+":"+row.gecos+":"+row.home_directory+":"+row.shell))
```

And then insert this list in your second table.

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant but it looks like this is the simplest solution. As a result, I implemented a [copy()](https://gist.github.com/blaircraft/fc45d7f792841968a1dc) method in User that returns a newly instantiated User object that was constructed from the member variables.